# Prawn table method won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I have been creating pdf documents fine with prawn. I am using prawn 0.8.4. I have created a class in pdf folder in the app directory like so.

```
class SchoolPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(school)
    super(top_margin: 70)
    @school = school
    school_name
    line_items

  end

  def school_name
    text "School: #{@school.school_name}", size: 30, style: :bold
  end

   def line_items
    move_down 20
    table [[1,2],[3,4]]
   end
end
```

This is code from my show action in the controller

```
def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf  do
    pdf = SchoolPdf.new(@school)

    send_data pdf.render,filename: "#{@school.school_name}_report.pdf",
                         type: "application/pdf",
                         disposition: "inline"
  end
```

I get the error `undefined method 'table'` what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more context (more code, where are you using it etc), as I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: Hope that provides more context

Comment: It looks like you've based your code off the [Prawn Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised), whose code would seem to work.  Perhaps this is a version problem...?  Can you attempt to upgrade Prawn to `1.0.0.rc2`, or at least to `0.12.0`, and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes worked just needed to upgrade to `0.12.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Prawn version `0.12.0` and it should work.